# Who is faster Superman or The Flash

Tags: dc

Who is faster Superman or The Flash?                                 Already tried other comic sites.

Comment: You are going to give somebody an aneurysm by tagging this with [tag:marvel-comics].

Answer (score 4):

The Flash...and here's how we know...they have raced, numerous times.

Superman #199 (1967): Supes and Flash race, but intentionally pull a tie because a huge number of criminal syndicates were betting on the race, and they made sure there were no clear winners.

Flash #175 (1967): Another race...pulled to a draw when they realize the whole thing is a ploy to try to kill the Flash.

World’s Finest #198 – #199 (1970): Another 'race' but this one ends rather stupidly, with both characters having to crawl across a desert using only their arms to hit the power switch for a bunch of robots...Flash gets their first and Supes is technically the loser here.

DC Comics Presents #1 – #2 (1978): Flash technically wins again, but like the prior one...it happened through convoluted storytelling, and not an actual race.

The Flash Rebirth #3 (2009): We FINALLY get a proper race, and a fairly definitive answer. Supes is trying to chase down the Flash, and tells Barry that, as their numerous races have shown, Flash isn't fast enough to get away from him. Flash's responds with "Yeah, but those other races were for charity." And then accelerates even more, leaving Superman in the dust with ease.

So, given this, it's made pretty clear that all the times it was a 'close race' it was because Barry was keeping things interesting for the sake of charity, rather than just smoking Supes and calling it a day.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that the Flash finally unambiguously won one.  For decades, it was like nobody could have anything that Superman didn't.  "And the award for Fastest Runner/Most Brooding/Best Starry Blue Panties goes to: Superman."